# Can you create an UIImage from PDF data?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am loading a remote PDF file and trying to turn it into an UIImage (for showing in an UIImageView), and am surprised that it doesn't seem to work. Even though local PDF files in the Asset Catalog work just fine, is PDF not supported outside of that?

Edit: I found https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/LoadingImages/LoadingImages.html which suggests that nope, PDF doesn't work. So that leaves me with the question: why/how does it work for local files in the Asset Catalog? Why or how is that different?

Comment: This may help - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/core-graphics/how-to-render-a-pdf-to-an-image (note: it was the first result from searching with google for `swift use pdf as uiimage`)

Comment: Yes I found some other libraries that do this as well, but I really was curious why it doesn't work natively, while Asset Catalog PDF's do work natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your *"Why or how is that different?"* question...

When you add a PDF file to asset catalog, Xcode renders `@1x, @2x and @3x` versions at build-time.

You *can* select `Preserve Vector Data` to have the pdf "rendered on-the-fly." This generally works well, although if you have a lot of pdfs and you're doing a lot of manipulation with them, it *may* reduce performance.